# How to get a clicked object position on different dimension using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, click, position

I am facing issue while developing one of My `jQuery` task. As....
I have a responsive Image(Working on all mobile device resolution), My Task is when I click on that image, I want to get a image position on which the image clicked.. I tried to complete this task using Page X and page Y behaviour of `jQuery`.but it gives the different value when I changed the resolution of screen.

Please help me and give me suggestion or provide a sample how can I do this. I guess position should be same even if the resolution would be different.

Comment: please more describe your problem, you want to change z-index of image ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure understand your issue but i think you want to do this
If i wrong please share your codes and more describe your isssue

```js
$(function (){
  'use strict';
  
  $('.img1').click(function (){
    $('.img2').css({
      'z-index': 3
    });
  });
  
  $('.img2').click(function (){
    $(this).css({
      'z-index': 1
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
}

.box .img1,
.box .img2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.img1 {
  background-image: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-e8VRnumXmR0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAUQ/uk_p3w15PNs/photo.jpg?sz=128);
  z-index: 2;
}

.img2 {
  background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5768f7edd993f3f1a5363f6d786d5ace?s=128);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="img1"></div>
    <div class="img2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the CSS `z-index` by jquery:

```
$(target).css({
   'z-index': 2
});
```